# How to read and alter packet info when forwarding

Tags: networking, server, iptables, routing, sockets

I have two laptops running ubuntu(both 20.04.4 LTS x86_64) and im trying to use one as a router(lets call them laptop1 and laptop2 and laptop2 is acting as a router). So far ive used the ip route command to change the default gateway of one of laptop1 to 192.168.1.85(ip address of laptop2) and on laptop2 ive used iptables and sysctl to enable ip forwarding to laptop2's gateway(192.168.1.1) and things are working fine. Now lets say, i want to apply a certain encryption on the contents of the packets coming from laptop1 and then forward them, how can i do that? Ive searched a lot and i couldnt find anything similar. Ive used the linux socket library before and its ok if the solution requires me to write my own program.

Also is it possible to do this when the laptops arent on the same network?

So basically what i want to do is i want laptop2 to listen to all incoming traffic, alter their content, and send them to another server.

Any hints on how i should do this and where to start?

Comment: There is no mention of any version of Ubuntu in this question. Please EDIT and add the version info.

Comment: No, you can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You ask several questions so let me address them one at a time.

> "Can this be done when the laptops aren't on the same network?"

No, not in a way that will properly be accepted at either end.  Especially if one system is mobile and the other is at a fixed location.  That's not how packet forwarding and mirroring works.

> Basically, the question is: "Can I read packet data, alter it, and then apply changes to the packets because I want to encrypt it specially".

No.  Encryption is an Application layer (L7) task and packets are not L7.  Taking a packet, altering its encryption, and then making that 'usable' is impossible as the data stream will no longer have the proper checksums, etc. for packets and therefore not properly function in terms of reconstructing the datastream.

Yes, you can listen for packets and then forward those packets elsewhere by encapsulating the raw packets in new packet streams to your 'other server', but altering the data is not going to function as expected, as packet streams, etc. for most things (on TCP) have checksums and you will hard-break everything that you were 'keeping' the packets for in this approach.

<sup>(Due to site Terms of Service/Use and personal qualms about teaching people how to implement this, I won't detail *how* this could be achieved. The reason I know how this would be done, though, is because I'm an IT Security professional)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Thats what i did first. I wrote a C program to open one socket on localhost amd listen for incoming traffic and tried to connect a socket to 192.168.1.1 to send those packets to(basically bringing them back to application layer and packaging them again) but that didnt work. Firstly the socket on localhost didnt really receive anything and secondly opening a socket to 192.168.1.1 failed with errno 111. Can you please share some light on that?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I'm not going to go into details on implementation, etc.  Because that'd essentially be a "how to" to create a trojan RAT and monitor someone's traffic if I go into how this could be done.  Which would be against site Terms of Use relating to malware and such.